# How to make time series forecasting with 20 Independent variable and one target variable?

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, time-series, data-science

In a problem I am working on I have to make time series forecast to predict a dependent variable a with 15 different Independent variable b1,b2,b3..b15.in python  will the linear regression work? I am new to predictive modeling..

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please take a look around and read [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). This question is really broad, but briefly: linear regression is often a key building block in forecasting methods, but how you set up the problem depends on what your goals are. There are some libraries specifically for Python that may help with this, see [tslearn](https://tslearn.readthedocs.io/en/stable/), [sktime](https://www.sktime.org/en/stable/), or [tsai](https://timeseriesai.github.io/tsai/).

Answer (score -2):

Yes linear regression will work!
Lets say you are having a time series [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10].
Assume you are having three inputs and one dependent output, you can form your dataset like

```
#input = [1, 2, 3] output = [4]
#input = [2, 3, 4] output = [5]
#input = [3, 4, 5] output = [6]
#input = [4, 5, 6] output = [7]
#input = [5, 6, 7] output = [8]
#input = [6, 7, 8] output = [9]
#input = [7, 8, 9] output = [10]

inputs = [[1, 2, 3],
         [2, 3, 4],
         [3, 4, 5],
         [4, 5, 6],
         [5, 6, 7],
         [6, 7, 8],
         [7, 8, 9]]

outputs = [[4], [5], [6], [7], [8], [9], [10]]
```

Now train the model using the inputs and their respective output

```
lr = LinearRegression()
lr.fit(inputs, outputs)
```

Comment: Just saying "linear regression will work" is a little irresponsible. Linear regression might work, if there is no observations that are correlated also if the observations are evenly spaced in time (forever), and even if these needs are met, it's not a particularly good way of doing this, an autoregressive algorithm is a far stronger choice.